# Excel VBA: Assigning name to a cell via code, relatively to another named cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code that adds a certain number of cells (downwards) after a given cell (named cell_22c in the example below). (11 cells are added per section - nbDR is the amount of sections). After every 11 cells inserted, I'd like my code to name the cell "cell_22c_j" where j would be a number in a "for" loop also dependent on nbDR. I have researched the Names function and tried using a recorded macro, but I did not manage to reference an existing cell! code:

```
Dim nbDR as integer
Dim i as integer
Dim j as integer
For j = 1 to nbDR
    For i = 1 To 11
            Range("cell_22c")(7).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next i
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Names.Add Name:="cell_22c_" & j, _
        RefersToR1C1:="=Overview!R45C38"
next j
```

It should insert 11 lines, then name a cell in the section. Insert 11 more and name a cell in the new section, etc.

I believe my code is good, except for the RefersTo part, obviously, which is the part I need help with (I think).

Comment: I believe it could refer to cell_22c with an offset of 11*j ? How could I write that?

Comment: What is *nbDR* and do you want a number or a letter as the last character in the name? e.g. `Chr(107)` is a *k*

Comment: nbDR is a number specified by the user. I won't describe my whole program but in short, a DR (Design Review) is an 11-rows long section with information that will be placed into it later, with another sub. It will vary between 1 and 6. The last character shall therefore be a number between 1 and 6. >cell_22c_1, cell_22c_2, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of understanding what your code is attempting to accomplish is hampered by the super-secret nature of your project but I believe it essentially boils down to the following.

```
Dim nbDR As Long, j As Long
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")
    .Range("cell_22c")(7).Resize(11 * nbDR, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    For j = 1 To nbDR
        .Range("cell_22c")(7 + j * 11).Name = "cell_22c_" & j
    Next j
End With
```

There is no need to loop through inserting the rows. Just insert all of them at once and then loop through and assign the names in the most short-cutted manner possible.

Comment: ++ nice on resize :) That totally skipped my mind :)

Comment: Thanks - I do have a concern that *cell_22c* may be wider than a single cell. That is one of the things I just couldn't determine from the OP's sample. The new ranges were assigned to a single cell so it may be OK.

Comment: It is indeed a single cell. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim nbDR As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rw As Long, col As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")
    
    '~~> Change this to whatever you want
    nbDR = 5
    
    With ws
        '~~> Get the current row and coloumn of the named range
        rw = .Range("cell_22c").Row
        col = .Range("cell_22c").Column
    
        For j = 1 To nbDR
            For i = 1 To 11
                '~~> Insert 1 cell below
                .Range("cell_22c").Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Next i
            
            ws.Names.Add Name:="cell_22c_" & j, _
            RefersToR1C1:="=" & ws.Name & "!R" & rw + 11 & "C" & col
            
            '~~> the below is only for testing purpose
            'Range("cell_22c_" & j).Value = "cell_22c_" & j
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit**: If the range("cell_22c") has more than one row/columns then change the value of `rw/col` accordingly for example

```
rw = .Range("cell_22c").Row + .Range("cell_22c").Rows
```

and then

```
.Range("cell_22c").Offset(1)
```

becomes

```
.Range("cell_22c").Offset(rw+1)
```

Similarly, if required, handle the `col` as well.